# Python: Mimic of import function

Tags: python, import, python-import

Suppose I have a big program with many calls to other libraries and I want to seek how does it work by slowly changing every function.
For the sake of argument: I have:

```
import numpy
print numpy.sqrt(2)
...(many other calls to numpy.sqrt)
```

And instead of importing numpy I want to create my internal function sqrt. I see this something like that:

```
#import numpy

def numpy:
    def sqrt(x):
        return x


print numpy.sqrt(2) #now program calls my own numpy.sqrt function
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy

def sqrt(x):
    return x

numpy.sqrt = sqrt
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I need, but I'll try this way.